# Why a function defined in let can be used outside of the function?

Tags: f#, ocaml, sml, ml

Here is the code from book 《compiling with continuations》,page 16(I rewrite it f#):

```
let (x,y)=
  let g(a,b:int,c)=a+c in
  (g,g(1,2,3))
```

So `x` can be the function `g` defined in let.

Maybe it's fine according to the ml grammar, but in "engineering practice", it seems the function defined in "let in" of a function, or where and let in Haskell, it should be "private", like o-o language, it should be a "tool function" used in the function.

So is the example code right? Maybe the program can run, but I don't think it's a good practice; ml should prevent it, like using "private".

Comment: "Private" protection, like scope, applies to names, not to values. You should be able to do the same in an "OO" language where functions are "first-class" values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function in OCaml is a first class value. There is no problem returning a function from a function.

Everything is perfectly well defined (essentially it has the semantics of the lambda calculus). When viewed as a value, a function carries with it the environment that it needs (i.e., it is a closure).

I don't personally see any more problem returning a function than returning a data structure. If you get experience with OCaml you might start to look at it this way.

Comment: In addition to this answer I would add one more thing that seems to be confusing the op. variables `x` & `y` are already in top-level scope so what we are doing is defining a function g in an inner `let` scope and just returning that function (here `g`) as a value to be bounded to top level `x`